# How do I call a partial view with IEnumerable collection in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i want display a Slider within the webpage slider page is partial

```
 <div class="slider">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", new IEnumerable<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>)
    </div>
```

iam see this error

Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable

i am remove new IEnumerable and just keep it as

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml") in the view
```

iam see this error
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 6:          @foreach (var item in Model)
Line 7:          {
Line 8:

this code view slider

```
@model  IEnumerable< Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>
```

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
                <li>
                    @{ 
                       string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(@item.FImage);
                       string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                    }
                    <img src="@imageSrc" class="info" width="100" height="50" />
                </li>
            </ul>
    }
```

how sloved this problem

Comment: can you show the view from where you are calling you need to pass model to it

Comment: iam try replce this code new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>() but trace view show  The code inside the loop will not run   @{
  }
           @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
                <li>

                    <img src="~/Content/Images/main/sliderengine/main2.png" alt="main2" />
                   
                </li>
            </ul>

        }

Comment: you need to show the view in which your are calling ``@Html.Partial()``

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand your solution

Comment: i am saying you are writing ``Html.Partial()`` in a View, can you show that view in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iam sloved this problem

```
  @Html.Action("slidshow", "slider")

 public  ActionResult slidshow()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/slider/slidshow.cshtml", GetSliderImages());
    }
  public IList<slidShow> GetSliderImages()
    {
        var q = db.slidShows.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_SlidShow).Where(x=>x.st==false);
        return q.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate `IEnumerable<T>` with a `new` keyword as it is an interface. You can instantiate a class implementing that interface such as
`new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>()`
Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) to understand inerfaces better

Comment: iam dont show error when replace this codenew List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>()  but return null modal while  modal is not null

Comment: I am guessing by modal you mean whatever the partial view would render. If that is the case, then yes, it would be empty as the collection `new List<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>()` would be empty. What you could do is have a property on the View Model that you are passing to your View. Something like

Comment: That property could be of type `IEnumerable<Mvc_baker.Areas.admin.Models.slidShow>`. You would then pass this property to the `Html.Partial()` call. Something like `@Html.Partial("~/Views/slider/slider.cshtml", Model.SlideShow)`. This would allow you to set the property outside of the view with some real values.